# Complete integral of pde without independent variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Show that the complete integral of pde $F(u,p,q)=0$ ($p=u_{x}$ and $q=u_{y}$) is
$$
f(x,y,u,a,b) = x + ay + b - \int\frac{du}{g(u,a)},
$$
where the function $p=g(u,a)$ is computed from the differential equation. I have started with writing Charpit system, namely:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{ds} = F_{p} \\ 
\frac{dY}{ds} = F_{q} \\
\frac{dP}{ds} = -F_{u}P \\
\frac{dQ}{ds} = -F_{u}Q \\
\frac{dU}{ds} = PF_{p} + QF_{q}
\end{cases}
$$
where $X=X(s), Y=Y(s)$ is some curve in the $x-y$ plane which is parameterized with the $s$ and $U(s)=u(X(s),Y(s))$, $P(s)=u_{x}(X(s),Y(s))$, $Q(s)=u_{y}(X(s),Y(s))$. I don't know what to do next - how can I find the solution without more knowledge about the function $F$? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we have to assume that $F_pF_qF_u\neq 0$, i.e., $F(u,p,q)$ is a non-trivial function of its arguments. In this case, it follows from the third and fourth Charpit's equations that
$$
\frac{dp}{dq}=\frac{p}{q} \implies q=ap. \tag{1}
$$
Plugging this result in $du=pdx+qdy$, and defining $\xi:=x+ay$, we obtain
$$
du=p(dx+ady)=pd\xi \implies p=\frac{du}{d\xi}. \tag{2}
$$
In addition, substituting $q=ap$ in $F(u,p,q)=0$ gives $F(u,p,ap)=0$; solving this equation for $p$ yields
$$
p=g(u,a). \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ we finally obtain
$$
\frac{du}{d\xi}=g(u,a) \implies \xi+b = \int\frac{du}{g(u,a)}
$$
$$
\implies x+ay+b-\int\frac{du}{g(u,a)}=0. \quad{\square} \tag{4}
$$