# Do the transformation and find a complete integral

Tags: characteristics, partial-differential-equations

> Consider the equation $x^2p^2 + y^2q^2=u$. 
>   Do the transformation $(x,y,u) → (\bar x,\bar y,\bar u)$ deﬁned by 
>   $$\bar x = \ln x,   \bar y = \ln y,    \bar u = u$$ 
>   and obtain an equation involving only $\bar p$ and $\bar q$. Find a complete integral of this equation and express the ﬁnal result in terms of the original variables $x,y,u.$

First I did the transformation.

$$F=x^2p^2 + y^2q^2-u=0$$

$$p=u_x= u_\bar x \bar x_x + u_\bar y \bar y_x=  u_\bar x /x$$

$$q=u_y= u_\bar x \bar x_y + u_\bar y \bar y_y= u_\bar y /y$$

$$F=0=x^2p^2+y^2q^2-u= x^2(u_\bar x /x)^2+y^2(u_\bar y /y)^2-u$$

$$0=u_\bar x^2+u_\bar y^2 -u$$

$$0=\bar p^2 + \bar q^2-u$$

But I am confused because question is like that "obtain an equation involving only $\bar p$ and $\bar q$." But I also have $u$ in my equation. What is my mistake? If someone solves my question, I would appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that you've applied the transformation at all. You're still using the old coordinates.

Comment: @Leia. You correctly found the transformed PDE : $$(\bar p)^2 + (\bar q)^2= \bar u$$ Then  are they some boundary conditions specified in the wording of the problem ?

Comment: @JJacquelin no boundary condition but I think we can solve complete integral without boundary condition, is it right? and isn't it false that the equations involves $\bar u$? I am not sure because of part of question (involving only $\bar p$ and $\bar q$)

Comment: Another transformation than $\bar u=u$ is necessary to get $(\bar p)^2+(\bar q)^2=1$.

Comment: "Involving only $\bar{p}$ and $\bar{q}$" probably means "without $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$", so the transformed PDE $(\bar p)^2 + (\bar q)^2= \bar u$ does the job. For the second part of the question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737189/complete-integral-of-pde-without-independent-variables/4863110#4863110.